# why there are few projects without nib file

Tags: iphone, ipad, coding-style

I recently worked in a ipad project. I find no nib files in the entire project. Is there a specific reason for such standards? I find it really difficult to follow that kind of project.

Comment: i've got the opposite problem... when projects has all objects in IB... so i started to use just code-objects and to avoid IB... and let me say: it's been very helpful to understand (for an object-c ignorant as me) how iPhone projects work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I would consider this a "standard". Some devs just prefer to code all their views as opposed to using Interface Builder. The initial releases of IB were a bit flaky and people avoided it due to this. I don't really see any reason to avoid using IB nowadays unless you are doing a completely custom user interface or a game. In the case of a custom UI, it might be easier to build it up in code compared to trying to bend the IB elements to your will.

Answer (score 1):

a nib, particularly if localized, breaks DRY.

initialization is beyond your control when using a nib.

code and program reuse is more difficult. consider libraries and multiple apps.

it's easier to manage/update an implementation from fewer locations/files/resources. let's say you want to change the app's color theme... very painful if you have to modify all the app's nibs, as opposed to changing the definition of a function. also pretty close to useless if you layout the groundwork at the source level for color themes in addition to using nibs -- at that point, you're already setting up your views programmatically.

improved performance (where that's important).

program security. IB used to support plugins/addons in osx... those were just removed.

frameworks are not an option in iOS. nibs can't be shared via libraries as easily as compiled programs.

for long term and large scale development, it makes a lot of sense to write it programmatically, whereas IB's really handy for prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, IB is pretty stable and a lot more featured that it used to be. Although iirc using IB does add more weight to the project than if it was all done via code.